# Stuck with dependencies in an AppX from Desktop App Converter

Tags: windows, desktop, appx, appxmanifest

I have finally succeeded converting my desktop app to AppX with Desktop App Converter, and to sign it with the insight from [Franklin Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5254458/franklin-chen-msft).

Step by step, I am getting closer to completion. But I am now bumping into a new hurdle (hopefully the last). I tried to follow the advice at 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

I did install on my machine vc_uwpdesktop.110.exe, vc_uwpdesktop.120.exe and vc_uwpdesktop.140.exe.

But still not joy. When I try to install the AppX, I get this error message :

```
Ask the developer for a new app package. This
package may conflict with a package already
installed, or it depends on things not installed
here (package dependencies), or is made for a
different architecture (0x80073CF3)
```

20161015 - More information :

I tried to use add-appxpackage as instructed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> add-appxpackage –register C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles\AppxManifest.xml
```

Here is the result on the command line :

> add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
>   Windows cannot install package CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt because this package depends on a framework that could not
>   be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft
>   Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 12.0.40652.5, along
>   with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" currently installed are: {}
>   NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 147c2bae-26c2-0005-268c-7c14c226d201 in the Event Log or use the command
>   line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 147c2bae-26c2-0005-268c-7c14c226d201
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + add-appxpackage –register C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles\AppxM ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\output\Check...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

As instructed, I have fetched the log :

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AppxLog -ActivityID
>   147c2bae-26c2-0005-268c-7c14c226d201
>
> Time                      ID           Message
>   ----                      --           ------- 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     301          The calling process is powershell.exe 10/15/2016 5:41:58
>   PM     603          Started deployment Register operation on a package
>   with main parameter: AppxManifest.xml and
>                                          Options: DevelopmentModeOption. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help
>                                          diagnosing app deployment issues. 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     10002        Creating Resiliency
>   File
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\76c1ec66-a626-417f-be
>                                          73-95fd9ce4b88f_S-1-5-21-2501171662-860024267-76414939-1001_1.rslc for
>   Register Operation on
>                                          Package CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt. 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM
>   607          Deployment Register operation on package
>   CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt has been
>                                          de-queued and is running for user DESKTOP-V1EBBS5\mitch. 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     613
>   Adding uri to the list of Uris:
>   C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles\AppxManifest.xml. 10/15/2016
>   5:41:58 PM     628          Windows cannot install package
>   CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt because this
>                                          package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework
>                                          "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" published by "CN=Microsoft
>   Corporation, O=Microsoft
>                                          Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and
>                                          minimum version 12.0.40652.5, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name
>                                          "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" currently installed are: {}
>   10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     605          The last successful state
>   reached was Indexed. Failure occurred before reaching the next
>                                          state Resolved. hr: 0x80073CF3 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     401          Deployment Register operation
>   with target volume C: on Package
>                                          CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt from:  (AppxManifest.xml) 
>   failed with error
>                                          0x80073CF3. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>                                          deployment issues. 10/15/2016 5:41:58 PM     404          AppX Deployment operation failed for
>   package CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt with
>                                          error 0x80073CF3. The specific error text for this failure is: Windows cannot install
>                                          package CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt because this package depends
>   on a
>                                          framework that could not be found. Provide the framework
>                                          "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" published by "CN=Microsoft
>   Corporation, O=Microsoft
>                                          Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and
>                                          minimum version 12.0.40652.5, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name
>                                          "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" currently installed are: {}

Now I don't understand why it does not find Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop. I have downloaded and installed vc_uwpdesktop.120.exe 12.0.40653.00 and double verify it as not only in programs and features, but on the disk where it is supposed to be.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting this error from the App Installer. Try installing it from PowerShell with `Add-AppxPackage`, and examine the output (and activity log) for a clearer indication of what occurred. If there's anything specific, add it to your question.

Comment: Reply appreciated. I am on the road, away from my development machine. Will resume at end of the week.

Comment: OK. Back at my desk.

I don't understand where I should use Add-AppxPackage. Sorry.

I tried to add it to the DesktopAppConverter Command Line, but all I get is an error.

Comment: DesktopAppConverter -Installer C:\setups\CWIIISilent\setup.exe -Add-AppxPackage "/S" -Destination C:\Output\ -PackageName "CompleteWindowIII" -Publisher "CN=Match Software" -Version 3.2.0.0 -MakeAppx -Verbose

Comment: It must be very simple and I am probably too ignorant. Will appreciate enlightenment :)

Comment: Once you have a signed .appx file, you can open PowerShell and use the [Add-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx) cmdlet to "install" it. It will probably fail like the App Installer does, but should provide additional information, either directly, or through the activity log.

Comment: I have done that and added it to the question to be able to show all error messages and logs. I don't understand why Add-AppPackage does not find Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop when indeed, I have installed it in my system. What is it expecting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the update. That confirms what the problem is. It was actually described in your original post, but it's quite subtle:

> I did install on my machine vc_uwpdesktop.110.exe, vc_uwpdesktop.120.exe and vc_uwpdesktop.140.exe.

Unfortunately this did not do what you think. It installed the .appx files that can be used to redistribute the framework dependencies. It did not actually install the framework dependencies themselves.

To install them, you have to find the .appx files they installed (or at least the 120 x86 version) and ensure they are also installed. You can do so directly with the App Installer, with Add-AppxPackage separately (and ahead of time), or, I believe, as part of your package's installation by referencing the framework dependency in a -DependencyPath argument.

The path to the .appx file in question looks something like this; tweak the version numbers and platform for your case as required. Just make sure you don't accidentally use a variant without "Desktop" in its name.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop.*110*\14.0\Appx\Retail\*x86*

Once you install or reference the correct package here, your main package should install (or register) successfully.

Comment: Michael, how can I thank you enough for that clear, concise and so so helpful reply ?

This solved entirely an issue I had been struggling with for several weeks now. This should be mentioned somewhere on the page about dependencies. I am going to add it there if I can.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. As for thanking, stick with the usual. You already accepted the answer; feel free to also upvote it if you think it deserves it. Pay it forward when opportunities come up.

Comment: How do I upvote ? I will make sure to share what I received. Actually several Xojo developers are anxious to see me complete submission to the Windows Store and I promised to post a complete step by step how to at http://forum.xojo.com