# DesktopAppConverter : Still trying to convert a Win32 app to a working AppX

Tags: windows, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have been at it for over a month, now.

I am able to convert my Win32 app to an AppX with the DesktopAppConverter and sign it, but I still get the error :

---

> Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict
>   with a package already installed, or it depends on things not
>   installed here (package dependencies), or is made for a different
>   architecture (0x80073CF3)

---

At the end of the conversion process, the converter displays this :

---

> W_PACKAGE_DEPENDENCY_ADDED A dependency on framework package
>   'Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop' was added to the
>   AppxManifest.xml. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821959'
>   for guidance on installing the package prior to local deployment.
>   Otherwise, if this is in error, remove the corresponding entry from
>   Dependencies in the AppxManifest.xml before packaging and deploying
>   your application

### .

So I checked https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

Downloaded vc_uwpdesktop.120.exe (version 12.0.40653.00) and installed it.

Then, following instructions at the page above, tried to repackage my app with :

```html
MakeAppx pack /d C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles /p C:\output\CheckWriter3.appx
```

Still the same error. So I tried :

```html
add-appxpackage –register C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles\AppxManifest.xml
```

Now I get :

> add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
>   Windows cannot install package CheckWriterIII_3.2.0.0_x86__eqr0y32pbpypt because this package depends on a framework that could not
>   be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft
>   Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 12.0.40652.5, along
>   with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop" currently installed are: {}
>   NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 147c2bae-26c2-0000-36d8-7c14c226d201 in the Event Log or use the command
>   line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 147c2bae-26c2-0000-36d8-7c14c226d201
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + add-appxpackage –register C:\output\CheckWriterIII\PackageFiles\AppxM ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\output\Check...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

I have tried to follow to the best of my ability the Msdn literature, looked all over the Internet for guidance, and am still stuck.

It seems not many people actually use the DesktopAppConverter, or are willing to share their knowledge.

Really, I would appreciate a hand.

Mayday !

Comment: Could you please share the detailed event log by following the exception you got: Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 147c2bae-26c2-0000-36d8-7c14c226d201

Comment: Hi Franklin, the issue was that I did not know I had to install the AppX after installing the vc distribuable exe. After I did so, the app ran flawlessly. Thank you.

Comment: Good new:) Could you please share some important steps for others who have the same issue?

Comment: Sure ; I intent to write a step by step how to. I will let you know through your openszone address when I have found the time to do so. Will probably post it first in the Xojo forum (http://forum.xojo.com).

Comment: Would love to hear your voice and refine our document:)

Comment: Let me send you an email, then :)

Comment: Hi, @MitchMatch any chance for an answer on this? I am about to run into this issue myself any moment now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GrigorySergeev See the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39743615) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40066045) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the guidance described in this blog post for handling the dependency on VCLIB runtime libraries:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Reading initial blogs gave me great hope that Microsoft had produced something to convert my old win32 apps. Hovever, the reality is that it is a pain in the ass to use so I'm not going to bother. I'll concentrate on Android development which has a relatively easy deployment system.